# Парсинг double значений

Tags: android, синтаксический-анализ, android-edittext

Доброго времени суток! Пишу простенький калькулятор,но столкнулся с такой проблемой: второе введённое число не парсится и в итоге,если ввести "5+8", то получим "10". Подскажите, как решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Код:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    inputNum1 = 0;
    inputNum2 = 0;
    result = 0;
    try{
        inputNum1 =  Double.parseDouble(mInputVal.getText().toString());
        inputNum2 =  Double.parseDouble(mInputVal.getText().toString());
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnZero:
        case R.id.btnOne:
        case R.id.btnTwo:
        case R.id.btnThree:
        case R.id.btnFour:
        case R.id.btnFive:
        case R.id.btnSix:
        case R.id.btnSeven:
        case R.id.btnEight:
        case R.id.btnNine:
        case R.id.btnP:
        break;
        case R.id.btnDiv:
            result = inputNum1 / inputNum2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnMult:
            result = inputNum1 * inputNum2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnSub:
            result = inputNum1 - inputNum2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            result = inputNum1 + inputNum2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnExit:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.btnClear:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    inDigit = ((Button)view).getText().toString();
    if(strVal.equals("0")) {
        strVal = inDigit;    // no leading zero
    } else {
        strVal += inDigit;   // accumulate input digit
    }
    mInputVal.setText(strVal);
    if(inDigit.equals("C")){
        mInputVal.setText("");
        tvResult.setText("");
        strVal = "";
        result = 0;
    }
    if(inDigit.equals("=")){
        tvResult.setText(strVal + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: "а в чем же еще? естественно, ты вставил "\ + ", split не нашел попадания и вернул всю строку в val[0], и при попытке обратиться к val[1] выпадает выход за пределы массива." afiki,так а что нужно было вставить?

Comment: "\\+" тут нет пробелов.

Comment: юзаю без пробелов,всё равно падает(

Comment: ок. вчитался в код. странная логика. очень. получается сначала вводится первое число, потом знак операции и сразу же вычисляется.
так то нужно сначала всю строку выражения сформировать и парсить только при нажатии на "=".

Comment: фуф...всё переделал,всё заработало!)спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parseDouble не угадывает какое из чисел тебе нужно. давай ему конкретные строки. для этих четырех операций и двух операндов можно сделать так:

- нади индекс символа с операцией(+, -, /, *);
- берешь строку от начала до этого индекса и парсишь в первое число;
- берешь строку после индекса и до конца и парсишь во второе число.

Comment: попытался для одной операции сделать так:
 String[] val = mInputVal.getText().toString().split(" + ");
        try{
            if(null!=val && val.length>1){
                inputNum1 =  Double.parseDouble(val[0]);
                inputNum2 =  Double.parseDouble(val[1]);
            }
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
но ничего не вышло,числа теперь вообще не парсятся

Comment: .split("\\+"); тут два обратных слеша. один сайтом съедается. в документации по методу написано, что принимает regex. можно было и погуглить как правильно использовать метод.

Comment: да погуглил уже,спасибо)

Comment: хотя всё равно,второе введённое значение не парсится

Comment: ты оставил пробелы в выражении для split. если нет, то опиши подробнее какие входные данные.

Comment: вряд ли дело в пробелах,юзаю inputNum1 =  Double.parseDouble(val[0].trim());
            inputNum2 =  Double.parseDouble(val[1].trim());, падает FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: а в чем же еще? естественно, ты вставил "\\ + ", split не нашел попадания и вернул всю строку в val[0], и при попытке обратиться к val[1] выпадает выход за пределы массива.